# Clock() and delay()

Tags: c

На сколько правильно учитывает функция clock() задержку времени вызванную функцией delay() в языке С?

```
    void testClock(){
     clock_t start, end;
     start=clock();
     delay (1000);//1s=1000ms
     end=clock();
     printf("%f\n", ((float)(end-start))/CLOCK _PER_SEC);
    }
```

Цифра не соответствует действительности. Или что то не верно понял?

Comment: А сколько получается? 1.1 - 1.2 ?

Comment: Без delay() - 0.000008; c delay(2000) - 0.102666

Comment: Может double попробовать? Может это из за точности?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что должно быть вроде 0.002000? Или около этого.

Comment: Должно быть >= 2.000, а что за функция delay()? В какой ОС пишете программу?

Comment: Стандартная функция заморозки программы. time.h. Linux под raspberry.

Comment: @PavelGridin исходя из программы разве не >=0.002000?

Comment: Если задержка 2000 мсек, то clock-время деленное на CLOCKS_PER_SEC должно показать 2 секунды. CLOCKS_PER_SEC: "Clock ticks per second"

Comment: Если это windows, поставьте Sleep вместо delay всё будет ок

Comment: @PavelGridin ос на базе Linux

Comment: тогда usleep(2000000)

Comment: @PavelGridin кроме предупреждения о не декларированной функции, особо ничего не изменилось. Показывает что то около 0.104247.

Comment: значит какие-то особенности raspberry, попробуйте посмотреть на https://electronix.ru

Comment: @PavelGridin спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Читаем man:

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The clock() function returns an approximation of processor time used by the program.

Обращаю ваше внимание на слова «processor time». Функция `delay()` **не использует** процессор. Поэтому задержка, которую она вносит **не учитывается** в потреблённом процессором времени.

Для работы с *астрономическим* временем есть функции:

- `time()` — с точностью до секунды,
- `gettimeofday()` — с точностью до микросекунды.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Безусловно внесло ясность. Интересно Ваше мнение по поводу цифр которые я писал выше. 
Без delay() - 0.000008; c delay (2000) - 0.102666. Как можно правильно инвестировать их?

Comment: Я работаю на люнихе (Ubuntu) и *delay*  у меня отсутствует - поэтому проверить не могу. Но, из общих соображений можно предположить, что 8 мкс - это просто время передачи управления от одного оператора до другого. А вот откуда взялись 200 мс при вызове *delay* - не очевидно. Ясно, что часть этого времени -  время, потраченное на вызов ядра. Но, слишком много... Может быть это время работы динамического загрузчика, который загружал *so*, содержащую эту функцию. Попробуйте собрать программу статически и сравнить время...

Comment: Спасибо что уделили время